# How to set background image from database in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So, I want an object that will have background image assigned from database. I have found some solutions but none of them had part that would get image from database. This is how I set regular image:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/' + Location.image_1)}}" alt="{{Location.name}}">
```

So, logically I tried same thing with background>

```
<div class="" style="background-image: url('{{url_for('static', filename='images/' + Location.image_1)}}') height: 25vh;">
```

Nope, doesn't work. Tried different variants without url('...') or something like that.

Anyway if someone has solutions I would apricate it

Answer (score 0):

Try This Once :

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=f'images/{Location.image_1}')}}" alt="{{Location.name}}">
```

or

```
<div class="" style="background-image: url('{{url_for('static', filename=f'images/{Location.image_1}')}}') height: 25vh;">
```

this can prevent from concatenation error of different data types.
if you get error after this then try to check what you receive in Location and Location.image_1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest search for errors in browser console. I also suppose that you put images folder in ...static/images/

You also can to use [test_request_context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_request_context) to evaluate url_for.
see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#url-building